# Tensorflow - concat single pixels features

Tags: tensorflow, concatenation

I'm new to Tensorflow, I'm processing a number of feature maps from two images. At a certain point, I've N features map for each of the two images and I want to obtain a single, feature volume concatenation of the two.
I can simply concat them with tf.concat([features1, features2]), in order to obtain a new volume having, for each pixel, the features at that position from both images.
What if I want to concat features with pixels having different coordinates on the two images?
For example, I've a function mapping x,y from the first image to u,v on the second image. Such functions does not follow a shared rule for all pixels (e.g., it's not a simple horizontal translation). Using numpy arrays, the behavior should be this:

```
  for i in range(0,H):
    for j in range(0,W):
      u = f(x)
      v = f(y)
      concat[i][j] = np.concatenate([image1[y][x], image2[v][u]])
```

I tried to slice single pixel features and concat them together within for loops, but as you know it's very inefficient (and infeasible with large images, the memory required is just too high).

```
  matrix = []
  for y in range(0,H):
    row = []
    for x in range(0,W):
      row.append(tf.concat([tf.slice(image1, [0, y, x, 0], [-1, 1, 1, -1]), tf.slice(image2, [0, v, u, 0], [-1, 1, 1, -1]) ], 3))   
    row_array = tf.concat(row, 2) 
    matrix.append(row_array)
  result = tf.concat(matrix, 1)
```

What's the best option, it it exists?

Comment: I found splitting feature maps into lists of Tensors leading to a more efficient solution, bust still far from being good. This removes the WxH slicing operations inside the loops:

     row.append(tf.concat([image1_features[0][y][x][0], image2_features[0][v][u][0], 3))